# Windows Phone 7 - passing selected item (listbox databound to ObservableCollection) to "update" page

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I am writing a Windows Phone 7 Application that should be pretty basic.

I have a view model ("MainViewModel") that contains a class I created ("EntrySheet"), which contains an ObservableCollection (I'll refer to it as "Entries").

My MainPage.xaml contains a listbox that is databound to the App.ViewModel.EntrySheet.Entries.  This works perfectly for showing the list, and adding entries to the ObservableCollection is reflected in the ListBox.

However, what I can't get my head around is the proper way to "pass" a selected Entry to an update page (this will let a user change fields on the Entry: name, amount, date, whatever which when navigated back to MainPage will be reflected in the ListBox).

I guess what I expected what for there to be a "SelectedItem" on the ObservableCollection, and I could just navigate to the update page, which would be able to use something like: App.ViewModel.EntrySheet.Entries.SelectedItem.

I really appreciate any help on this and would also welcome constructive criticism on how to better structure my app.

Comment: Does anyone have any input on this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to figure out one possible solution, but it feels...messy.

I added a static instance of my class 'Entry' and an integer called selectedIdx

When a user "taps" an item in the list, I set the App.Entry to the tapped list item, set the selected index, and then navigate to the edit page.

In the edit page, when the user clicks 'save' I am able to update the proper Entry in my App.ViewModel using the selected index.

This doesn't seem to be the "right" solution, but if this is the way everyone else is doing it, I'll learn to live with it!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late anwer, but I just happened to stumble across your question now.

Here's a possible solution for you:

**XAML**

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" Tap="listBox_Tap">
    <!-- Some code -->
</ListBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void listBox_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    DataObject dataObject = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as DataObject;
    //Do something with dataObject
}
```

This will enable you to interact with the data object behind the selected item in the listbox.

Courtesy of [Windows Phone Geek](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/WP7-ListBox-SelectedItem)